# Very similar MySQL queries results significantly varying query durations (WHERE on timespans)

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL table with around 600 K rows in it (Engine: InnoDB). 
MySQL is running in a virtualbox machine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in it. MySQL server version is 5.7.23, if that's relevant.

The columns in the WHERE clauses (`open_time` and `close_time`) are both indexed and they are both DATETIME columns.

The column that I'm taking the sum of (volume) is a double.

This query returns instantly (0.000 seconds):

```
SELECT *
FROM klines
WHERE (open_time between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-01 12:00:00')
;
```

EXPLAIN output: 
[image]

Whereas this one takes almost a second to fetch (varies between 0.640 and 0.703 seconds between 10 tries):

```
SELECT SUM(volume)
FROM klines
WHERE open_time >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND close_time <= '2018-01-01 12:00:00'
;
```

EXPLAIN output: 
[image]

Mind that both queries returns about the same rows (720 for first, 721 for the second. Second query returns the same 720 rows which first one returns, plus another one).

So, if I want to get just the rows, it does not matter if I use WHERE clause for two columns or one. But if I want to get the SUM of a column, query gets drastically slower when I use WHERE clause for two columns. If I use a single column however, it again returns instantly.

While I'm perfectly OK with using the query which queries the table using between two open_time criterias, I'm really curious about what's going on.

So, what would be the reason behind this?

Comment: The queries are not the same. `open_time between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-02 00:00:00'` means `open_time >=  '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and open_time <= '2018-01-02 00:00:00'` which is **not** the same as `open_time >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND close_time <= '2018-01-02 00:00:00'` and will (probably) yield completely different results.

Comment: You are right, they yield different results but result sets are more or less the same. If I query for half a day worth of data (say from 2018-01-01 00:00:00 to 2018-01-01 12:00:00), one query yields 720 rows while other one yields 721. The 720 rows which has been fetched by the first query are the same 720 rows which is fetched by the second, second query has just one more row than the first one.

Comment: Ah, I see that only now, these are different queries, it makes sense they will take different time. If you want to figure out why, run execution plans on both, and write a new question with them attached .

Comment: @sagi I've just updated the question.

Comment: As you can see, one is using a range scan, and the other isn't. So the differences are reasonable, why is another question. though. This question is old now, I suggest you open a new one if you want to figure out why. Add only the two relevant queries, their execution plan , and the indexes (You didn't provide them and it's not clear how they are defined - Two different index or one) .

Comment: Ok, will do in a minute. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open_time between '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
              AND '2018-01-01 12:00:00'
```

can easily use `INDEX(open_time)` to touch only the interesting rows.  But it is not possible to have an index that stops abruptly for this:

```
     open_time >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
AND close_time <= '2018-01-01 12:00:00'
```

`INDEX(open_time)` could be used, but the last half of the table would be scanned.  `INDEX(close_time)`, similarly, would scan the first half of the table.  And there is now way to do both.

You *probably* have an additional constraint that is nowhere visible:

- [open..close] time ranges don't overlap?
- open is always < close?

These cannot be specified in standard SQL, nor is there any index formulation that would take advantage of either constraint.

Here are two rows that will mess up any optimization attempt:

```
INSERT INTO klines (open_time,             close_time)
            VALUES ('2018-01-01 06:00:00', '2037-12-31'),
                   ('1971-01-01',          '2018-01-01 06:00:00')
                   ('2037-01-01',          '1971-01-01')
```

There are fixes, but they require either assuming non-overlapping, then playing with the queries is severe ways; or playing with buckets.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Time ranges are indeed non overlapping and open is always < close.  And time delta between each row's open_time column is just one minute, always. As I mentioned, I was happy with using between (open_time xxxx and xxxx), I was just wondering why this was the case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SercioSoydanov - what is the 'max' timespan between open and close?  Office appointments tend to be in a very limited range, such as 1/2 to 2 hours.  This would lead to one kind of solution.

Comment: This table holds the minutely values for the cryptocurrencies, open and close times are maximum one minutes away, rarely slightly less. So I solved it with giving constraint between two open times. Queries are much faster now.